# Internal redirection to tomcat from IIS 7.0?

Tags: tomcat, iis-7

I am running some sites on IIS 7.0. But yesterday one of my client asked me to host a Java website. I can't host that website directly so I installed tomcat server on port 8080. Whenever a browser send a request for that website, it should redirect to my tomcat internally. The client URL should not be updated.

Answer (score 19):

I was originally going down the same route as James but there is a much better (and for some reason less known) way.

Since you are running IIS7 you can setup Microsoft [Application Request Routing](http://www.iis.net/download/applicationrequestrouting). This will allow you to create a proxy from IIS to Tomcat. [Here](http://dannybaggs.wordpress.com/2010/05/14/iis7-tomcat-application-request-routing/) is a walk through on a blog. I have an [example on my blog](http://bronumski.blogspot.co.uk/2010/10/host-teamcity-in-iis7.html) showing you how you can host multiple sites in IIS and route traffic based on the host header name. I did have a link to another blog but this is no longer available.

Comment: OK, not very experienced in setting up server stuff, so just to confirm: I want to have `domain.com/folder1/all.php` and `domain.com/folder2/java_servlets`, both on the same port. Is that what this does?

Comment: Yes you can do that. \you just need to work out the rules in order to get it to redirect properly. Essentially IIS becomes a front end web server which forwards on traffic to the backend services which may or may not be running on the same machine. There are other prehaps better products that do the same but if you haver windows you get it for free.

Comment: I saw lots of hand rewriting rules. With workers and rewrite map it is easy

Comment: Worth to read https://grokbase.com/t/tomcat/users/113pw13wj3/pros-and-cons-of-jk-connector-vs-arr

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Tomcat IIS connector. IIS will accept the request from the web browser, send it on to Tomcat, get the response from Tomcat and send it back to the web browser

http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/iis.html

Comment: Feel I must share. It is an old post so you may not be looking. Have a look at my answer. I came across the Application Request Routing extension for IIS7 today, it is a lot easier and cleaner than the ISAPI redirector.